# Docker-compose tutorial not working "python: can't open file 'manage.py"

Tags: django, docker-compose

I am running simple Docker-compose example shown [here](https://docker.github.io/compose/django/)

Here is Dockerfile:

```
 FROM python:2.7
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 RUN mkdir /code
 WORKDIR /code
 ADD requirements.txt /code/
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ADD . /code/
```

Here is docker-compose.yml:

```
 version: '2'
 services:
   db:
     image: postgres
   web:
     build: .
     command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
     volumes:
       - .:/code
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
     depends_on:
       - db
```

When I am trying to launch the example with docker-compose it gives me following:

```
alex@universe:~/projects/testcompose$ docker-compose up
testcompose_db_1 is up-to-date
Recreating testcompose_web_1
Attaching to testcompose_db_1, testcompose_web_1
web_1  | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
db_1   | The files belonging to this da...
```

Probably tutorial is not up to date so if you know answer please write it here.

Comment: Have you ran this command: `docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .` inside folder with `docker-compose.yml`? It will actually create `manage.py` and all Django related files inside Docker Volume.

Comment: Yes, I did it. Actually the problem was that after running this command the project structure was not correct. It has created additional composeexample folder with project and manage.py file inside. After moving all the files one level up everything was working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, project file structure was generated correctly.
Django always has a `my-project-folder/my-site/my-site` file structure.

To make it work with docker-compose you just need to move up the following files to `my-project-folder/my-site/`

```
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
requirements.txt
```

`my-project-folder/my-site/` already contains `manage.py` file (if that is not the case then something is wrong)

At this point make sure that `my-project-folder/` only contains 
`my-site/` folder and nothing else.

Once everything is setup correctly just move up to `my-project-folder/my-site/my-site`
execute command `docker-compose up` 
it will build everything needed.
execute command `docker-compose up` a second time and there you have it.

Dont forget to check allowed host and add '0.0.0.0' on `settings.py` file if needed.

that's all.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `docker-machine` or Docker Toolbox this is likely caused because the project is not under the `/Users` directory. Only that directory is availabled as a shared folder in the VM.

You can remove the `volumes:` from the config, or add another shared folder to Virtualbox.

Comment: @dhephin thanks for the answer! I am not using docker-machine on Ubuntu. The problem was with not correct project structure after starting Django project inside container.

Answer (score 1):

I arrived here with the same error message, turns out I was simply forgetting to add the dot `.` at the end of the below command:

`docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .`

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue while following this docker basic tutorial https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

So, basically I was at the same stage and I am also noob in docker. My approach was first of all I used the below command to identify the contents inside my image directory make sure your django project is available in that directory

```
docker run -it container_name sh
```

after that you will be getting this error when you run docker-compose up command

> web_1  | python: can't open file '/proto/manage.py': [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory

So, basically docker is executing instructions from your Dockerfile and it is executing your python manage.py runserver command in code folder which doesn't contain your manage.py file.

So, add this line it will navigate you to the folder which consists manage.py file

```
CMD . /code/composeexample/
```

and now build your project again with

```
docker-compose build
```

Now run the command below and you are good to go

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Where should I add `CMD . /code/composeexample/` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was using pipenv which creates virtualenv,
my problem was i forgot use

```
RUN pipenv shell
```

to enable virtualenv.

but using `pipenv shell` in container makes some problem
so the solution is use `--system` option with `pipenv install` command

```
RUN pipenv install --system
```

which causes packages to be installed on container itself and not on virtualenv in the container.